# Javascript, Hour comparisson

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

Having two strings (start and end time) in such form "16:30", "02:13" I want to compare them and check if the gap is greater than 5 mins.

How can this be achieved in Javascript in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function parseTime(time) {
  var timeArray = time.split(/:/);
  // Using Jan 1st, 2010 as a "base date". Any other date should work.
  return new Date(2010, 0, 1, +timeArray[0], +timeArray[1], 0);
}

var diff = Math.abs(parseTime("16:30").getTime() - parseTime("02:13").getTime());
if (diff > 5 * 60 * 1000) { // Difference is in milliseconds
  alert("More that 5 mins.");
}
```

Do you need to wrap over midnight? Then this is more difficult. For example, `23:59` and `00:01` will produce a difference of 23 hours 58 minutes and not 2 minutes.

If that's the case you need to define your case more closely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following:

```
if (((Date.parse("16:30") - Date.parse("02:13")) / 1000 / 60) > 5)
{
}
```

Comment: `Date.parse` is not very smart about the input it gets and accepts only some predefined formats. So trying to parse plain time component probably fails and you should provide a date context too `Date.parse("01/01/2010 "+"16:30")`

Answer (score 1):

```
// time is a string having format "hh:mm"
function Time(time) {
    var args = time.split(":");
    var hours = args[0], minutes = args[1];

    this.milliseconds = ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60)) * 1000;
}

Time.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.milliseconds;
}

// converts the given minutes to milliseconds 
Number.prototype.minutes = function() {
    return this * (1000 * 60);
}
```

Subtracting the times forces the object to evaluate it's value by calling the `valueOf` method that returns the given time in milliseconds. The `minutes` method is another convenience method to convert the given number of minutes to milliseconds, so we can use that as a base for comparison throughout.

```
new Time('16:30') - new Time('16:24') > (5).minutes() // true
```

Answer (score 1):

This includes checking whether midnight is between the two times (as per your example).

```
var startTime = "16:30", endTime = "02:13";

var parsedStartTime = Date.parse("2010/1/1 " + startTime),
    parsedEndTime = Date.parse("2010/1/1 " + endTime);

// if end date is parsed as smaller than start date, parse as the next day,
// to pick up on running over midnight
if ( parsedEndTime < parsedStartTime ) ed = Date.parse("2010/1/2 " + endTime);

var differenceInMinutes = ((parsedEndTime - parsedStartTime) / 60 / 1000);
if ( differenceInMinutes > 5 ) {
   alert("More than 5 mins.");
}
```